# Android Views: can checking visibility before setting visibility improve performance?

Tags: android, performance, android-view

I have helper methods that set the visibility of certain `View`s depending on the state variables that are passed into the methods. Sometimes, these methods will get called many times and the `View`s visibility will not change. So I found myself starting to check the visibility of each `View` before setting it with the thinking, *"No point in changing a View's visibility to the same visibility and causing a refresh for no reason"*.

```
            if (myView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            etc...
```

However, now I'm wondering if the implementation of `setVisibility` already takes this into account, and checks if you are setting the same visibility to what the `View` already has, and doesn't needlessly refresh the `View` (what my code is trying to do).

So does anyone know if my "optimization" is actually improving any performance, or is the API already a step ahead of me?

Comment: yes, you are improving the performance, because you dont tell the VM to load `setVisibility` every time.

Comment: @Geobits actually as you said, setting the visibility will not refresh the view if the visibility is the same, but if he is asking for code performance in his case this will improve.

Comment: but `setVisibilty` will call another methods:1- `setFlags` , 2- `mBackground.setVisible`

Comment: and all these methods will be loaded even they will not work.

Comment: I was more concerned with not refreshing the `View`, the method calls to check the visibility are negligible (in the scope I'm looking to improve on). I just wanted to make sure I wasn't making a check that was already happening (which I now know is). Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

They're already one step ahead. See the code for `View.java:setVisibility()`:

```
public void setVisibility(int visibility) {
    setFlags(visibility, VISIBILITY_MASK);
    ...
}
```

It calls `setFlags()`:

```
void setFlags(int flags, int mask) {
    int old = mViewFlags;
    mViewFlags = (mViewFlags & ~mask) | (flags & mask);

    int changed = mViewFlags ^ old;
    if (changed == 0) {
        return;
    }
    ....
}
```

It checks to see if the flag matches the current state. If so, it simply returns without doing anything.

Comment: Bingo, exactly what I wanted to know. I'll remove my double checks and save myself some readability. Thank you sir!

Comment: I was about to create similar flag .. lucky to see your answer .